# How to implement HDRF algorithm?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I need to implement HDRF: Stream-Based Partitioning for Power-Law Graphs algorithm using Apache Spark Graphx in Scala and I have below dataset-

```
  1   2
  1   3
  1   5
  2   4
  2   5
  2   6
  3   4
  4   6
```

How to implement this algorithm? Any tips would be appreciated.

If needed I also have this pdf that can help you: http://slideshare.net/AndreaCingolani/03-hdrf-presentation . However for now i have been able to load the graph but i do not understand how to do partitioning in hdrf. I tried to implemement the algorithm in the partitionStrategy class of graphx with poor results

/* EDIT */

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.PartitionStrategy.{HDRF}


/**
  * Main
  */

object Main{

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("HDRF"))

    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val graph= GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,"data/sample_graph.txt")

    val numPartition= graph.partitionBy(HDRF)


  }
}




case object HDRF extends PartitionStrategy {

    val partSize:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](8)
    var vertexAssignment:Array[VertexId] = new Array[VertexId](8)

    override def getPartition(src: VertexId, dst: VertexId, numParts: PartitionID): PartitionID = {

    }

}
```

Inside the HDRF object that is in Graphx PartitionStrategy class do not know what to write

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that array `partSize` and `vertexAssignment` is not globally maintained acrossed worker, because as far as I know, HDRF algorithm needs to know both information.